# How to dynamiclly bind to a property path of an Object?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i have the following ItemsControl defined, i want to bind the Content of a Button to a object Property path, which will be provided as a string through a method. The Items are generic. How can i achieve this ? because i can't set DisplayMemberPath and bind it to the ItemTemplate. (i cant't set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate)

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="5 3"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
                            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                            Margin="2"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SelectionViewModel<T> : DialogViewModelBase, IDialogViewModel
{
    // Fields
    private string _title;
    private bool _showTitleSeparator;
    private string _displayMemberPath;
    private IEnumerable<T> _items;

    // Properties
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; Notify(); }
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; Notify(); }
    }
    // Member Path to bind to
    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return _displayMemberPath; }
        set { _displayMemberPath = value; Notify(); }
    }
}
```

if i remove the ItemTemplate and simply bind the DisplayMemberPath of the ItemsControl to the Property in my ViewModel it works fine.

Comment: "provided as a string through a method in ViewModel." Does a method return the content to be displayed if so try if u can use property instead of method call or try to define a contentproperty in the viewmodel and set the value in method. Then bind this to content of button.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal no the method doesn't return the content, it just gets the property path as a string and this path will be used for all Items since they are generics.

Comment: Then declare a property in the class and assign the path to it inside method and bind the property to the content as described in the answer.

Comment: What do you set the `DisplayMemberPath` to when it works? You cannot bind anything to this property. You can only set it to a string that identifies the name of the source property, just like the first argument of the `{Binding}` markup extension does.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using a converter and reflection.

```
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Contains(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            { return null; }

            object source = values[0];
            string path = (string)values[1];

            Type sourceType = source.GetType();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = sourceType.GetProperty(path);
            return propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Binding has to be set with Path to the property name of the class whose list is bound to the ItemsSource.
if your class looks like:

```
Class MyItem{
    String Prop1 { get; }
}
```

Then binding will be

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Prop1}" />
```

Comment: since the Items are generic, i don't know which property to bind to, and that is why the property path should be provided by the user as a string, so something like Text="{Binding Path={Binding DisplayMember}}", which i know i doesn't work.

Comment: You must declare T as some interface type for this binding to work or an alternate way could be that your T class overrides ToString method.

Comment: the reason why i used generics is because i don't have control over the type of the items and it shouldn't be restricted to an Interface because the Items can also be the "Built-in" value types (string, int, long, etc...)